# PostgresException return null from GCP when call function have an error by constraint FK

Tags: npgsql

I am using Google Cloud Platform to host my database postgres 9.6.

I have sent data to force error in FK for an update, in `filas = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` the result is 0 rows, as I hoped. But `catch (PostgresException msg_exception)` does not recognize the exception and `PostgresNotice msg_notice = new PostgresNotice()` returns `NULL` too when try to use the `msg_notice`.

```cs
using(var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connString)) {
 conn.Open();
 conn.TypeMapper.MapComposite < DTO_Usuario > ("t_usuario");

 using(var transaction = conn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted)) {
  try {
   using(NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(@ "SELECT ent_usuario_update(@p)", conn)) {
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter {
     ParameterName = "p",
      Value = row_usuario
    });

    PostgresNotice msg_notice = new PostgresNotice();
    try {
     filas = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

     transaction.Commit();

     if (filas > 0) {
      row_usuario.Nom_usuario = msg_notice.MessageText;
     } else {
      row_usuario.Nom_usuario = msg_notice.MessageText;
     }

    } catch (PostgresException msg_exception) {
     transaction.Rollback();
     row_usuario.Des_cargo = msg_exception.SqlState;

    }
    return Ok(row_usuario);
   }
  } catch (NpgsqlException) {
   transaction.Rollback();
   return NoContent();
  }
 }
}
```

My function in Postgres:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.ent_usuario_update(
p_usuario t_usuario)
RETURNS void

update usuario
   set des_cargo=p_usuario.des_cargo,
       nom_usuario = p_usuario.nom_usuario,
       id_organizacion = p_usuario.id_organizacion
 where id_instancia = p_usuario.id_instancia
   and id_mandante = p_usuario.id_mandante
   and id_usuario=p_usuario.id_usuario;

GET DIAGNOSTICS filas = ROW_COUNT;

IF filas == 0 THEN
    RAISE INFO 'No se actualizo usuario % en instancia %', p_usuario.id_usuario,  p_usuario.id_instancia
    using message = 'No actualizo';
ELSE
    RAISE INFO 'Actualización Realizada'
    using message = 'No actualizo';
END IF;

RETURN;

END;
```

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL notices aren't raised as exceptions, because they're not errors - so try/catch won't yield anything. It's also not possible to simply instantiate a `PostgresNotice` and expect it to get automatically filled in when you execute a command.

To receive a PostgreSQL notice, simply subscribe to the `Notice` event on your connection:

```
conn.Notice += (sender, args) => Console.WriteLine(args.Notice.MessageText);
```